# IOS 9 - How do i get a value of textField in an UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to get a textField value from UIAlertController, but whenever I try to enter the value (Name) and display it on **label**, the output doesn't show anything.

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Test" message:@"Please Enter your name " preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"Person Name ";
        textField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        textField.secureTextEntry = NO;

    }];
    UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction
                                actionWithTitle:@"ENTER, please"
                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                {
                                    //Handle the ENTER button 
                                   // how to Display the name in the label

                                }];
    UIAlertAction* noButton = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:@"No, thanks"
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                               {
                                   //Handle no button. 
                               }];


    [alert addAction:yesButton];
    [alert addAction:noButton];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: use the yesButton handler block for display textfield details on label.

Comment: @JP_Mob can you please share some code by answering this question, Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick swift example I pulled from an old project

```
     alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Send", style:   UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
        if let textFields = alert.textFields {
            if let textField = textFields.first {

            }
        }
    }))
```

In your application it would like something like this:

```
UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"ENTER, please"   style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
{
    NSArray *textFields = alert.textFields;
    // Probably smart to do some nil checking here
    NSLogv(@"%@", textFields.first.text);
    // add to label like so
    label.text = textFields.first.text;
}];
```

Comment: i tried to use NSString instead of NSArray, it did't like it

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. The `. textFields` property is an array. From there you have to grab the first one which is where you can get your string.

Comment: so how can i display the value on a label. Thanks

Comment: From my understanding, when the user enter their name, we should have the input in textField, so how to take the input from textField and output to label

Comment: one more thing, i tried to enter first.text after textFields, it did't work